# Cannot create Android emulation with hardware keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator

For testing purposes I need to create AVD which looks like this:

[image: kbd]

But all my emulated devices look like this:

[image: no_kbd]

They contain only screen, without hardware keyboard. This is "New Device" dialog:

[image]

"Hardware keyboard present" doesn't have any effect. How can I get desired device configuration?

Android SDK is running on Win7 x64, completely updated.

Comment: i think  in "skin" you have to select "Skin with dynamic hardware controls"

Comment: Thanks. Post this as answer, please, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in "skin" you have to select "Skin with dynamic hardware controls" Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

[image: image emulator]

Try this config. For me results ok.